# c++ pointer to floats inside of vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a c++ vector:

```
        vector<float> floats;
```

Later, this vector is initialized. I don't know what the internal contents of the vector container are, but I want to know if it is possible to return a pointer to where the array of floats are. Specifically, I am using CUDA and I need to pass a pointer to an array of floats. I cannot pass it a vector. Is there a way I can do something like

```
float *dapointer = &vector[0];
```

or something like this? I want to be able to write to it as well, like

```
dapointer[some index] = 4;
```

I realize this violates the point of a vector, but this vector is used for "vector purposes" in many other places in the program, but I need CUDA to be able to access the data as well. I don't want to change all my other code around to use an array instead of a vector.

Comment: Your first line is exactly right. Your second one needs to lose the leading `*` since operator `[]` includes a dereference.

Comment: You will still need to either pin the host memory that was allocated by the vector (dangerous), copy the contents to a GPU buffer using cudaMemcpy, or define your own std::vector allocator that always pins memory. If the memory array is large then the best approach is to copy the portion of the array that you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach should work, **but be careful**. Upon modifications to the vector, you might be left with dangling pointers. non-`const` operations performed on a vector invalidate iterators, pointers & references to memory it manages. On way to make this safe is marking the vector `const`.

Comment: what "second approach". The first returns the pointer. I need to read the vector of floats on the GPU, by which I can only pass a pointer to an array of floats.

Comment: @Tommy I'd use the first approach **but** mark the vector `const`.

Comment: So I can read on the GPU, but cannot write from the GPU. Ok, I can work with that.

Comment: @Tommy no, that's not what I meant. The vector should be const, the pointer you get dosn't have to be. You can write into that memory, as long as you don't modify the vector (and by that I mean `push_back` or `resize`)...

Answer (score 1):

```
float *dapointer = &floats[0];
```

is all good.

(Note how funnily operator overloading ambiguates C's pointer syntax...)

Comment: @Mr.Anubis really or sarcastic? (sorry, I really can't decide)

Comment: no I'm serious, i.e really (don't even think I did, +1'ed though)  since only vector is the container which can be passed to C functions properly this way

Answer (score 0):

As the comment mentioned, your first line is one way of doing this.  But that line is undefined if the vector isn't at least size 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
float *dapointer = floats.data();
```

ref: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data